# Is there a way to use own custom data for traffic using the map?

Tags: leaflet, maps, mapbox

Is there a way to use own custom data for traffic using the gmap, mapbox, leaflet. I just want to show custom data set for traffic using the map like google map indicating traffic in different colors in lanes. I just want to show the same but using own custom traffic data.

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: The answer is [yes](http://www.strcat.de/questions-with-yes-or-no-answers.html). If this is not the answer you expected, then I encourage you to read https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and rephrase your question. Mentioning the format of your own custom traffic data will help.

Comment: @IvanSanchez I don't have any format right now but I am thinking of implementing this. I just want to know is there any API available for this?

Comment: Your yes/no question isn't really helping you here. There are many different approaches to this problem, it would help if you go a bit further with your description of what you want to achieve. Is there a Leaflet API to show traffic? No. Is there a way to draw on a Leaflet map to represent traffic? Yes, many ways. But the best way might not be using Leaflet functionality at all - Mapbox, for example, applies traffic flow data to the map tiles before serving them.

Answer (score 0):

there is no any Leaflet API to show traffic but you can applies traffic flow data to the map tiles before serving them by using **Mapbox** to draw on a Leaflet map to represent traffic.Here is the best approach that is not be using Leaflet functionality at all.

A web mapping library allows you to add a map to a web page and define the data it contains, its appearance, and a variety of functionality. Think of it like a toolbox filled with many different map-making tools that can be used together to build beautiful and interactive custom experiences.